# How can I show two file upload buttons once I select a choice in a switch

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

So I want both of the file upload buttons to be shown when I write the following code but just one of them shows (file1). Any idea how to show both of them? I need two have two buttons in one row for uploading files when that specific option in a switch is selected. Is there any option in Shiny to do so?

```
 "Load Manually"= fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                                      accept = c(
                                        'text/csv',
                                        'text/comma-separated-values',
                                        'text/tab-separated-values',
                                        'text/plain',
                                        '.csv',
                                        '.tsv'
                                      ), multiple=TRUE


           ),
           fileInput('file2', 'Choose file2 to upload',
                     accept = c(
                       'text/csv',
                       'text/comma-separated-values',
                       'text/tab-separated-values',
                       'text/plain',
                       '.csv',
                       '.tsv'
                     ), multiple= TRUE

           )

    )
```

This is what currently shown:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use `fluidRow` we can have multiple items:

```
 "Load Manually"=fluidRow(
            fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                      accept = c(
                        'text/csv',
                        'text/comma-separated-values',
                        'text/tab-separated-values',
                        'text/plain',
                        '.csv',
                        '.tsv'
                      ), multiple=TRUE


            ),
            fileInput('file2', 'Choose file2 to upload',
                      accept = c(
                        'text/csv',
                        'text/comma-separated-values',
                        'text/tab-separated-values',
                        'text/plain',
                        '.csv',
                        '.tsv'
                      ), multiple= TRUE

            )
          )
```

Here is how it would look:
[image]